# How to return count from ODATA result set

Tags: java, sql, odata, teiid, olingo

I am trying to get a count of my records from an Olingo ODATA (version 2) result set similar to the one below:

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Categories/$count

The above url returns 3, and there are 3 'values' as you can see if you remove the `/$count`.

I am working on local host, where this url:

```
localhost/odata/livingODATA/address/
```

returns a result set, but `localhost/odata/livingODATA/address/$count` returns the error:

```
TEIID30088 Unrelated order by column g0.id cannot be used in a SET query, with SELECT DISTINCT, or GROUP BY
```

I have tried adding an `order by`, nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a illegal SQL query sent from olingo to TEIID, which might still make logical sense but triggers a TEIID Error. However, olingo is trying to `SELECT` simply `count(*)` while adding an unused `ORDER BY g0.id` to the query. For details on this error see those [two](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TEIID-2821) [bugs](https://community.jboss.org/thread/230837) at the jboss community.

While this behaviour should be a issue for the Apache Olingo developer team, the `$inlinecount=allpages` uri-option could be at least for the moment a possible workaround. This adds a `odata.count` property to the result object containing a total count for your odata query, disregarding any `$top` or `$skip` options. This is a functionality meant for pagination purposes.

[Official OData v2 Example](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions#InlinecountSystemQueryOption)

```
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$inlinecount=allpages
```

Your URI could be

```
localhost/odata/livingODATA/address?$inlinecount=allpages
```

or to prevent the service from loading all data at once you could add `$top=0` and only load `coun t(*)`:

```
localhost/odata/livingODATA/address?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=0
```

I hope this helps to get a few steps further.

Comment: This was a great solution, however, this does not solve it for me. as the "count" is equal to whatever my value for top is. instead of showing odata.count: "5" it shows _count: "5" (or whatever is top). Im wondering if the data format on the db is an issue, it shouldnt be though

Comment: It seems the operation is part of the 4.0 version, but was referenced in the 2.0 'uri conventions': http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/ poor docs. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can override the value for inline count by

```
ODataEntityProviderPropertiesBuilder propertiesBuilder = EntityProviderWriteProperties
                            .serviceRoot(serviceRoot).inlineCountType(InlineCount.ALLPAGES).inlineCount(dataSet.getTotal());
```

By the way it is working with version 2